# Is there an algorithm that can guarantee collection order while retaining O(1) insertion/deletion?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

Javascript's object properties supposedly has no order, but it appears to be sorted by insertion order in most browser implementations.

How could they achieve this without making insertion/deletion of object properties O(log n)? What sort of bookkeeping/algorithm could achieve this?

Or are they only tracking the insertion order when the number of properties are small?

Comment: Insertion order is simply a push onto a stack, (adding to an array) it's not at all complex.

Comment: @Blindman67 you still need to maintain it: if a key was removed, how would you remove a corresponding value from the stack/array?

Comment: http://jayconrod.com/posts/52/a-tour-of-v8-object-representation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be to start off with a hash table, and to also create a doubly linked list of pointers to the key-value pairs in the hash table. When you insert an item, add it to the tail of the doubly linked list. When you remove an item, remove it from the doubly linked list. You have the choice of completely ignoring writes to existing keys or treating them as a remove followed by an insert. When you need to iterate through the key-value pairs, move along the doubly linked list from the head to the tail.

Comment: "When you remove an item, remove it from the doubly linked list." --- how do you do that in `O(1)`?

Comment: In the hash table, along with the value, store a pointer to the node of the list that points to that key-value pair.